# Create an alarm from a string?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an app that generates random times, then stores those times in separate TextViews. Is it possible for me to set alarms up for these times using AlarmManager? I've seen other bits of code on this site and they all show the alarm time hardcoded. Stuff like this for example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

Obviously I can't do that because my times are random. So my app will generate a few times and next to each I add a button that reads "Set alarm". The user can also pick their own time, but that's in a String as well.

How do I get the String/TextView to be used as the time to set the alarm? If it helps the times appear in a 24Hr format.

Appreciate any help!

EDIT: Here is part of what I have now.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
userEnterTime = (userTime.toString(formatter));


Intent a = new Intent(this, Alarm.class);
a.putExtra("usertime", userEnterTime);  
startActivity(a);
```

Activity 'a' then assigns it to a TextView.

Comment: Why you don't just generate it dynamically in Calendar format rather than strings? Then you can show them in TextView as plain text if you want.

Comment: How would that work? Part of my let's users pick their own time via a TimePicker, that time then gets formatted into a String using DateTimeFormatter and then passed in an Intent to another class where it is shown in a TextView. I'll add a bit of my code from the class that gets the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply parse the String and split it at the colon to get the hours and minutes, then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert them to ints, and pass them to the `Calendar.set()` method.

```
String yourTime = "hh:mm"; //replace with time

String arr = yourTime.split(":");

int hours = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int mins = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

You should add a `try-catch` for `NumberFormatException` while you're about it.

Comment: Isn't that still hardcoded? Since String yourTime has a set time on it? I use a TimePicker to let my users pick a time for part of my app, I then convert it to a string and pass the intent to another class which then displays it in a TextView

Comment: @RED_ You can assign yourTime whatever value you want, from a TextView, or an Intent Extra, or a TimePicker, or whatever. I was just giving an example.

Comment: Ah i see. For what it's worth I've added a bit of my code to my question to show you what I have got going on.

Comment: @RED_ you can simply get the usertime intent extra and assign it to yourTime

Comment: Well, currently nothing happens because the AlarmManager side of things haven't been added so I'll accept this answer if this all ends up working.